# Grails Auto generated code is with warnings and errors

Tags: intellij-idea, grails, plugins, ide

I am using Intellij IDEA Ultimate and have Grails plugin installed. When i auto generate, let's say controller i have warnings like so : "Cannot infer argument types " for this code :

```
multipartForm {
                flash.message = message(code: 'default.created.message',
                        args: [message(code: 'tekEvent.label',
                                default: 'TekEvent'), tekEventInstance.id])//We need id to see in created message
                redirect tekEventInstance //redirect will open show() view and populate it with instance's data
            }
```

And an error for `'tekEvent.label'` .

Have MANY errors in generated views as well. It's not just me. My 3 fellows in team have the same problem as well. Would like to get a "**Light**" from you and pass it to them as well . Thanks ^_^

Comment: "Would like to get a "Light" from you and pass it to them as well ." - Are you asking how to configure IntelliJ to not report the concern?

Comment: What is Grails version? Please provide a sample project to check.

Comment: https://github.com/Xaxage/TekDays Here is that project.  The same problem have my coworkers . Version is 2.5.6 from book. Project is from  Grails2: Quick-start guide book.

Comment: I would i am asking how to make IntelliJ understand that everything is correct and not bother me with wrong errors and warnings .

Comment: Does the application work correctly? You can suppress warnings/errors, see https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/disabling-and-enabling-inspections.html#suppress-inspections

Comment: It work without any problems. This code is auto generated and it can't have any problems. It is IDE problem . And i don't want to turn off inspections. I want intellij to correctly understand code without any warning or errors :)

Comment: I've created an issue for this: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-293898/Grails-2-5-project-reports-Cannot-infer-argument-types-error-on-

Comment: Thanks. If any answer to come, post it here . I'll mark as a solution.

Comment: FYI... 2.5.6 has been EOL for quite a while now (we released grails 3 more than 7 years ago) and it would be a little surprising if JetBrains added new capabilities related to Grails 2.5.6 at this point.